# how to call a value from VHDL code file and put it in another code to show on FPGA LCD?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

i wrote a code of a counter and i need to get the final number i reached of the variable called "Sum" and put it in another code of a LCD FPGA , so how can i call or import this value in the other code ?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the question body, which by itself is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 components (modules) that can be used and connected (together) inside a separate code. Just create a separate design and use the modules as components and connect them together.

Comment: VHDL doesn't have 'module' in it's lexicon.  The term is 'block', either an internal block (from a block statement) or external block (defined by an entity declaration).  All concurrent statements are elaborated into either processes or block statements containing processes, or block statements containing block statements containing processes. And yes it's common for those conducting VHDL courses to superimpose 'module', a Verilog term.  Your 2 components would be subcomponents in another design unit and create instances of their respective components, which would be external blocks.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. In this question I think we have 2 separate components that each one has it's own entity and architecture. Then we can use the components (creating instances) in a separate code and connect them with some interface signals.